# "conda init" prevents anaconda-navigator from working on all but base environment

Tags: linux, ubuntu, anaconda

After running `conda init` from the terminal I am only able to run from the terminal `anaconda-navigator` from the base environment of anaconda.  I want to make it so that I can run `anaconda-navigator` from any environment including no environment.

I started down this because `conda activate myenv` would not work.  It recommended running `conda init`; so I did.  Previously I could run `anaconda-navigator` from any anaconda environment and it would pop up but now if I try from anything but base it doesn't work and I get this error message "anaconda-navigator: command not found".  However if I enter `conda activate` into the terminal to bring on the base environment the command works.

I just got done with a clean install of anaconda3 using the recommended steps https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux/

If I delete what `conda init` added to my .bashrc and add in 
`export PATH=/home/yourUserName/anaconda3/bin:$PATH`
then `anaconda-navigator` works again from any environement but `conda activate myenv` stops working.

FYI: I ran `conda config --set auto_activate_base False` after installing anaconda3

I expect to be able to run `anaconda-navigator` from any anaconda environment and to be able to use `conda activate myenv`.  Right now I can do one or the other by modifying my .bashrc